# How to transfer file from Django server to esp32?

Tags: django, esp32

I am working on a project where I have a Django server and an ESP32 with an SD card on it. I want to transfer a .wav file to the ESP32 through HTTP, however, I am not doing it the right way. The file is a little too big for the ESP32 to get, and I get an error, `[E][WiFiClient.cpp:517] flush(): fail on fd 48, errno: 11, "No more processes"`. I've been told that sending the file through JSON was a really bad idea, and I agree. I just don't know how else to send it. I tried this:

```py
def text_to_wav(voice_name: str, text: str):
  language_code = "-".join(voice_name.split("-")[:2])
  text_input = tts.SynthesisInput(text=text)
  voice_params = tts.VoiceSelectionParams(
      language_code=language_code, name=voice_name
  )
  audio_config = tts.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=tts.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)

  client = tts.TextToSpeechClient()
  response = client.synthesize_speech(
      input=text_input,
      voice=voice_params,
      audio_config=audio_config,
  )

  return b64encode(response.audio_content).decode("utf-8")


@api_view(["POST"])
def tts_view(request: Request):
  voice_name = request.data.get("voice_name")
  text = request.data.get("text")

  if not voice_name or not text:
    print("Missing voice_name or text")
    return JsonResponse({"error": "Missing voice_name or text"}, status=400)

  response = HttpResponse(text_to_wav(voice_name, text), content_type="audio/wav")
  response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s.wav" % text

  return response
```

However, I think this is for transferring a file to a web browser, not to an ESP32.

On the other hand, I am doing the request like this:

```cpp
void request_tts(string text, fs::FS &SD) {
  HTTPClient http;

  string server = SERVER_NAME;
  server += "tts/create-speech/";
  http.begin(server.c_str());

  string body = "{\"text\":\"" + text + "\", \"voice_name\":\"es-US-Neural2-B\"}";

  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Api-Key 0ZfAfvpE.y498gbIbw2QdKCCcJCIETRal1q9mjPy9");

  int response_code = http.POST(body.c_str());

  // Get payload
  String payload = http.getString();

  http.end();
}
```

I tried downloading [AsyncHTTPRequest_Generic](https://github.com/khoih-prog/AsyncHTTPRequest_Generic), but it just wouldn't compile, saying that I was missing a header file, something with STM32 (sorry, I don't remember the exact file that was missing, but I redownloaded it like 3 times, and it was a long time ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to stream the file in chunks. I had to modify both the server and the request in the ESP32 to manage this.

This is the modification in the server:

```py
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def text_to_wav(voice_name: str, text: str):
  language_code = "-".join(voice_name.split("-")[:2])
  text_input = tts.SynthesisInput(text=text)
  voice_params = tts.VoiceSelectionParams(
      language_code=language_code, name=voice_name
  )
  audio_config = tts.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=tts.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)

  client = tts.TextToSpeechClient()
  response = client.synthesize_speech(
      input=text_input,
      voice=voice_params,
      audio_config=audio_config,
  )

  return response.audio_content # Take out the b64encoding

def wav_streaming_iterator(wav_content):
  # Define the size of each chunk to be yielded
  chunk_size = 8192
  while True:
    # Get the next chunk of data
    chunk = wav_content[:chunk_size]
    # If there's no more data, break out of the loop
    if not chunk:
      break
    # Remove the chunk from the data buffer
    wav_content = wav_content[chunk_size:]
    # Yield the chunk to the caller
    yield chunk


@api_view(["POST"])
def tts_view(request: Request):
  voice_name = request.data.get("voice_name")
  text = request.data.get("text")

  if not voice_name or not text:
    print("Missing voice_name or text")
    return JsonResponse({"error": "Missing voice_name or text"}, status=400)

  # Generate the audio content as a WAV file and create a streaming 
  response object
  response = StreamingHttpResponse(
      wav_streaming_iterator(text_to_wav(voice_name, text)),
      content_type="audio/wav",
  )
  # Set the filename of the response
  response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="output.wav"'

  # Return the streaming response
  return response
```

The `wav_streaming_iterator` function is a generator function that takes in a block of WAV audio data as a byte string and yields it back to the caller in smaller chunks. This is useful for sending large audio files over a network connection, as it allows the data to be sent in smaller pieces rather than all at once.

The `tts_view` function is an endpoint for a Django REST framework API that takes in a voice name and text from the request data, generates a WAV audio file from the text using the `text_to_wav` function, and returns a streaming response object that iterates over the audio data in smaller chunks using the `wav_streaming_iterator` function. The `Content-Dispositio`n header is set to indicate that the response should be downloaded as a file named "output.wav".

And the way to manage this in the ESP32:

```cpp
void request_tts(string text, fs::FS &SD) {
  HTTPClient http;

  // Set the URL of the TTS API
  string server = SERVER_NAME;
  server += "tts/create-speech/";
  http.begin(server.c_str());

  // Set the text and voice name in the request body
  string body = "{\"text\":\"" + text + "\", \"voice_name\":\"es-US-Neural2-B\"}";

  // Set the headers of the request
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Authorization", "Api-Key 0ZfAfvpE.y498gbIbw2QdKCCcJCIETRal1q9mjPy9");

  // Send the POST request and get the HTTP response code
  int http_code = http.POST(body.c_str());

  // Check if the response code is OK
  if (http_code != 200) {
    http.end();
    throw runtime_error("Error requesting TTS");
  }

  // Set the filename for the WAV file to be saved
  string filename = "/audios/" + text + ".wav";

  // Open the file for writing
  fs::File file = SD.open(filename.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    http.end();
    throw runtime_error("Error opening file");
  }

  // Write each chunk of the response to the file as it arrives
  Serial.println("Writing to file");
  WiFiClient *stream = http.getStreamPtr();
  const size_t buffer_size = 512;
  uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes_read;
  while (http.connected() && (bytes_read = stream->readBytes(buffer, buffer_size)) > 0) {
    file.write(buffer, bytes_read);
  }

  // Close the file and end the HTTP connection
  file.close();
  http.end();

  Serial.println("TTS request completed");

  return;
}
```

The magic of this is that the response data is read in chunks of 512 bytes and written to the file.

So that's it.